# ORA 00933 : SQL Command not properly ended with IN operator in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update

I am trying to execute a query which is as follows

> update L2l_Lov_Master set QUERY_STRING =
> 'com.jmr.profitto.los.app.retail.model.L2LLdmLeadinformation entity
> WHERE entity.status IN ('NEW','REJECTED','REJECTED_BY_CUSTOMER')'
> where LOV_ID = 'customerLov-leadcode';

I am using oracle DB and i am getting "ORA 00933: SQL command not properly ended". Need to know where it went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you problem is related with the quotes --> to be more explicit, you have a problem when your `IN` clause starts because you close your first quote from query string

```
query_string = 'com.jmr.profitto.los.app.retail.model.L2LLdmLeadinformation entity WHERE entity.status IN ('
```

I think you need to encapsulate the quotes from the `IN` clause so that they get ignored by the first query.

```
UPDATE l2l_lov_master
SET
    query_string = 'com.jmr.profitto.los.app.retail.model.L2LLdmLeadinformation entity WHERE entity.status IN (''
new '','' rejected '','' rejected_by_customer '')'
WHERE
    lov_id = 'customerLov-leadcode';
```

Comment: glad to help. Just as info, when creating the statement, there might be some differences in the text, so make sure you correct them before using the code in your live project. ( within the IN Clause I used lower case and added some spaces )

Answer (score 0):

One can easily get lost with too many single quotes. Therefore, use the q-quoting mechanism, like in the following example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE l2l_lov_master
  2  AS
  3     SELECT 'customerLov-leadcode' lov_id, LPAD ('x', 500, 'x') query_string
  4       FROM DUAL;

Table created.
```

See line #3 and the end of line #4, i.e. `q'[blabla]'`.

```
SQL> UPDATE L2l_Lov_Master
  2     SET QUERY_STRING =
  3            q'[com.jmr.profitto.los.app.retail.model.L2LLdmLeadinformation entity
  4   WHERE entity.status IN ('NEW','REJECTED','REJECTED_BY_CUSTOMER')]'
  5   WHERE LOV_ID = 'customerLov-leadcode';

1 row updated.

SQL> SELECT * FROM l2l_lov_master;

LOV_ID
--------------------
QUERY_STRING
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
customerLov-leadcode
com.jmr.profitto.los.app.retail.model.L2LLdmLeadinformation entity
 WHERE entity.status IN ('NEW','REJECTED','REJECTED_BY_CUSTOMER')


SQL>
```